# DAX Nested Aggregate Contexts/Filters

Tags: ssas, dax

I'm trying to write a DAX calculated measure which uses nested aggregates to perform a calculation based on the user specified query context, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply the query context to the inner aggregation as well as the outer.  The simplified structure of my tabular data is below, where each Sale record represents the sale of a single widget by one user to another for the given sale price:

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8f87.png)

[image]

And some sample data:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM6lz.png)

[image]

The calculated measure query itself is below, which is essentially attempting to calculate on average how good of a bargain each buyer gets for their purchases.  It does this by performing the following calculations:

1) Inner 'Calculate': For each Sale record, Calculate the average Price the given Seller sells their widgets for (potentially filtered).

2) Outer 'Calculate': For each Sale record, Calculate the average of the Price minus the amount calculated in #1, essentially giving a differential in actual vs expected sale amounts.

```
Avg Actual/Expected Differential :=
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGEX (
            Sale,
            Sale[Price]
                - CALCULATE ( AVERAGEX ( Sale, Sale[Price] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Sale, Sale[Seller] ) )
        )
    )
```

This formula works in the standard case where no query filters are being applied but User related filters.  For example, the actual vs expected sales to Dale are:

- Sale from Larry for $2, where Larry's average sale is $3.5. Differential = -$1.5
- Sale from Bob for $5, where Bob's average sale is $3. Differential = $2
- Sale from John for $4, where John's average sale is $4. Differential = $0

Thus, the Avg Actual/Expected Differential is $.5 / 3 = $.17.

The problem I'm running into is applying a query filter on the `IsCashSale` field and having that filter apply to both the inner and outer `Calculate` functions.

For example, if I want to filter both inner and outer to only include Sale records which have a True `IsCashSale` value I can create the appropriate filter in the UI and the outer `Calculate` function is filtered appropriately, however when the inner `Calculate` runs, it removes this filter on `IsCashSale` as a result of the `AllExcept` function which removes the filters from all columns except the `Seller` field.

I tried including the `Sale[IsCashSale]` amount in the `AllExcept` field list, however because of the current row context, this only includes all records which have the same `IsCashSale` amount value as the current record of the inner 'Calculate' loop.  This causes the scenario where no filter has been applied to `IsCashSale` to be incorrect.

I believe I may be looking for a way to pass the selected Values from the outer `Calculate` to the inner one?  If I can do that, I can include those values as filters on the inner `Calculate`.  Is there a way to use something like the `Earlier` or `AllSelected` functions to do this?  Or is there another way to do what I'm attempting to do?  Thanks!

Comment: Note: I've been messing with the `KeepFilters` function, which appears to get me very close:

`Avg Actual/Expected Differential:=CALCULATE ( 
 AVERAGEX ( Sale, 
  Sale[Price] 
  - 
  CALCULATE ( 
   AVERAGEX ( 
    Sale, 
    Sale[Price]), 
    ALLEXCEPT(Sale, Sale[Seller]), 
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES(Sale[IsCashSale]))
  )
 )
)`

In this case, the values when I have applied the `IsCashSale` filter are correct, and 3 of the 5 values are correct when no filter is applied.

Comment: It's still not 100% correct, but it might be a start.  Can someone explain what's happening there?

Comment: Nevermind, it appears that removing the `KeepFilters` function but leaving the `Values` call results in the same.  Nothing special going on with `KeepFilters`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found a solution, but it's a bit convoluted.  It requires breaking out the sum of the individual purchases by the buyer from the average sales for each seller.  I believe the big difference was that by using the `VALUES(Sale[Seller])` set definition rather than just `Sale` it allows us to keep whatever filters are in place on the `IsCashSale` field in the outer `Calculate` function:

```
Avg Actual/Expected Differential:=CALCULATE(
(
    SUM(Sale[Price]) --Sum of Buyer purchases
    - CALCULATE (   
        SUMX( 
            VALUES(Sale[Seller]) --Calculate for each unique Seller
            ,CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Sale)) --Need to multiply by number of purchases from this particular Seller
            * CALCULATE ( --Get Seller's average sale price
                AVERAGEX (Sale, Sale[Price])
                ,ALLEXCEPT(Sale, Sale[Seller], Sale[IsCashSale])
            )
        )
    )
)
/ COUNTROWS(Sale) --Divide by total number of sales to get average
```

)

Answer (score 0):

How about using the ISFILTERED function?

```
Avg Actual/Expected Differential 2:=IF(ISFILTERED([IsCashSale]),CALCULATE (
    AVERAGEX (
        Sale,
        Sale[Price]
            - CALCULATE ( AVERAGEX ( Sale, Sale[Price] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Sale, Sale[Seller],Sale[IsCashSak]))
    )
),
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGEX (
        Sale,
        Sale[Price]
            - CALCULATE ( AVERAGEX ( Sale, Sale[Price] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Sale, Sale[Seller]))
    )
)
)
```

Now you will see the results like this when the IsCashSale column is filtered, and when it is not filtered it will behave the original way.

Are these the results that you wanted?

```
+----+--------+-------+-----------+--------------+------------------------------------+
| Id | Seller | Buyer | IsCashSak | Sum of Price | Avg Actual/Expected Differential 2 |
+----+--------+-------+-----------+--------------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | Bob    | John  | TRUE      |            1 |                                  0 |
|  2 | John   | Bob   | TRUE      |            2 |                                 -1 |
|  3 | Dale   | Bob   | TRUE      |            1 |                               -0.5 |
|  8 | Sue    | Bob   | TRUE      |            3 |                                  0 |
| 10 | John   | Dale  | TRUE      |            4 |                                  1 |
| 13 | Dale   | Kelly | TRUE      |            2 |                                0.5 |
+----+--------+-------+-----------+--------------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, that will work, but is it possible to put the `If` logic inside the filter list of the inner calculation?  Otherwise, writing the expression to cover a schema where there can be more than one filtered dimension becomes pretty huge.

Comment: You're right, I'm not a big fan of long formulas either, so I hesitated to share that answer.

Comment: This just came to me, how about not using nested CALCULATES in the first place? How about separating the CALCULATE functions, and then putting in [IsCashSale] in the ALLEXCEPT of the 2nd calculate? This formula gives the same results:

    Avg Actual/Expected Differential 3:=CALCULATE (
        AVERAGEX (
            Sale,
            Sale[Price]
        )
    ) - CALCULATE ( AVERAGEX ( Sale, Sale[Price] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Sale, Sale[Seller],Sale[IsCashSale]) )

Comment: `Avg Actual/Expected Differential 3:=CALCULATE (
        AVERAGEX (
            Sale,
            Sale[Price]
        )
    ) - CALCULATE ( AVERAGEX ( Sale, Sale[Price] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Sale, Sale[Seller],Sale[IsCashSak]) )`

Comment: I like the idea of simplifying it in that way, but I don't think that will work in the case where you are only filtering by the Buyer (e.g. Calculate the average of all differentials for all purchases by the Buyer across all Sellers), which is what I'm really interested in.  The first formula you gave will correctly handle that scenario.